# Being returned ORA-25408: can not safely replay call

Tags: php, oracle

This has to be one of the stranger bugs I've experienced.

File 1:

> ```
> logMyStuff('Before coolFunction'); 
> $this->obj->coolFunction();
> logMyStuff('After coolFunction');
> ```

File 2:

> ```
> public function coolFunction() {
>
> logMyStuff('Log 1');
> $sql = "update animals set cat = 'ragdoll'";
>
> try {
>
>   logMyStuff('Log 2');
>
>     $conn = oci_connect('mydb', 'epicPass', 'DB');
>     logMyStuff('Log 3');
>
>     if (!$conn) {
>         $m = oci_error();
>         logMyStuff('DB connect failure: ' . $m['message']);
>         return false;
>     }
>
>     logMyStuff('Log 4');
>     $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
>     logMyStuff('Log 5');
>
>     if (oci_execute($stid)) {
>         logMyStuff('Sweet it worked!!');
>         $return = true;
>     } else {
>         $m = oci_error($stid);
>         logMyStuff('Execute Error: ' . $m['message']);
>         $return = false;
>     }
>
>     logMystuff('Log 6');
>
> } catch (\Exception $e) {
>     logMyStuff('Something really bad happened'. $e->getMessage());
>     return false;
> }
>
> return $return; 
> }
> ```

99% of the time this works fine... but the 1% of the time our logs
look like this...

> [2017-05-08 14:00:00] - Before coolFunction
>
> [2017-05-08 14:00:00] - Log 1
>
> [2017-05-08 14:00:00] - Log 2
>
> [2017-05-08 14:00:00] - Log 3
>
> [2017-05-08 14:00:00] - Log 4
>
> [2017-05-08 14:00:00] - Log 5
>
> [2017-05-08 14:15:45] - Execute Error: ORA-25408: can not safely replay call

Things to notice...

- Log 6 logging doesn't appear.
- The Oracle execute is taking 15 minutes and 45 seconds to complete.
- Our script simply dies there... nothing else runs.

Although the error message from Oracle seems sinister, the thing I
find even more odd is the fact that the 'Execute Error:' log is able
to run but then the script dies.

Any ideas?